# What are the different types of functions you can create based on the position of the function call?

Tags: scala

`def atMost(actual: Int, limit: Int): Int = max(actual, limit)`

Say I have a function like above `atMost`, I have to call it like:

```
atMost(100, 25) // returns 25
```

What if I wanted to call it like:

```
val a:Int = 100 atMost 25
```

How would I write a function like that?

Also, what other styles of functions like this can you create?  Like reading from left, reading from right side possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So `100 atMost 25` will always be translated by the compiler as `100.atMost(25)`.
So, we can reformulate your questions as *"how we can add an additional method to an existing class"*, and the answer to that question would be **extension methods** *(as a general programming concept)* and **implicit classes** *(as the technique we can use in Scala to model that)*.

```
// AnyVal to avoid instantiation cost & private val to hide an useless actual extension method.
implicit class IntOps (private val actual: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def atMost(limit: Int): Int = max(actual, limit)
}
```

If that `implicit` is in scope, you can `100 atMost 25`.

---

> Also, what other styles of functions like this can you create? Like reading from left, reading from right side possible?

The other two important syntactic rules are.

- Unary methods.
- And right-associative methods.

For the first ones, you have to name them like `unary_{S}` where `{S}` is replaced by a single character which will be the unary symbol.
So a method defined as `unary_!` is to be called like: `!true`, which the compiler expands as `true.unary_!()`.

For the second ones, if the method name ends with `:` then that method is called in the right operand instead of on the left.
So a method defined as `++:` is to be called like `foo ++: bar`, which the compiler expands  as `bar.++:(foo)`.

Answer (score 4):

Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez explained how to add a method to an existing class using an implicit class in Scala 2.

I would like to add that Scala 3 will introduce a new syntax for this:

```scala
extension (actual: Int)
  def atMost(limit: Int): Int = max(actual, limit)
```

As you can see, there is no longer a need to create a new class for this use case. So it's more convenient because your don't have to come up with a name, your editor's type search won't be cluttered with these pseudo classes, there will be no useless allocations etc..

Scala 3 will be released before the end of the year, so it's time to start preparing :-)